# Want to declare block of code that uses a few EJBs to be transactional

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, ejb-3.1

I have a function that makes use of a couple of EJB facades that create some information in the database. This block of data creation calls should be atomic, if one fails, nothing should be committed. How do I make this block of calls transactional?

```
public myFunction() {
    ...
    ...
    userFacade.create(user);
    addressFacade.create(address);
    orderFacade.create(order);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can refer here  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html for transaction attibutes.

Comment: Just to be precise, the function `myFunction` misses a return type so it's not a function yet. It of course doesn't add up to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EJB3, if you are going to use declarative transactions  (container-managed transactions) then you would annotate these data access calls with either:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
```

which means these methods will join the currently ongoing transaction if it was there.
If (myFunction) is also an EJB method, then specifying `REQUIRES_NEW` will start a new transaction. The transaction will be rolled back when a system exception occurs but not application exceptions. This is why you need to use setRollbackOnly in this case.

More details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html

Answer (score 1):

In Java EE, EJB is the technology to work with transactions, and by default every business method is transactional - annotated with [@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) unless a bean provider changes it.

In you case, it would therefore be very beneficial to have the `myFunction` method a business method so a transaction starts upon entering the method and committed/rolled back upon leaving it. It will all be handled for you by the EJB container. When an exception is thrown the container will automatically roll back the transaction and in turn roll back all the operations in between.